# Create dynamic number of sliders in html from python list and display value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to create a dynamic number of sliders with value output according to a python dictionary `{{ sliders }}` fed in by a flask app.

So far I have come up with this code to display the sliders, but displaying their current value underneath each slider does not work.

The JS script will just display the default value of each slider not their current one. Why is that and how to fix it?

```
<div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('deployment')}}">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {% for slider in sliders %}
                    <div class="slidecontainer">
                        <p>{{ slider['name'] }}</p>
                        <input type="range" min="{{ slider['min'] }}" max="{{ slider['max'] }}" step="{{ slider['step'] }}" class="slider" id="{{ slider['slider_id'] }}" name="{{ slider['name'] }}">
                        <p>Value: <span id="{{ slider['value_id'] }}"></span></p>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        {% for slider in sliders %}
            <script>
            var slider = document.getElementById("{{ slider['slider_id'] }}");
            var output = document.getElementById("{{ slider['value_id'] }}");
            output.innerHTML = slider.value;

            slider.oninput = function() {
              "{{ slider['value_id'] }}".innerHTML = this.value;
            }
            </script>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the

```
document.getElementById()
```

in the `oninput`-function.

It should be

```
slider.oninput = function()
{
  document.getElementById("{{ slider['value_id'] }}").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```